# FBI digital fingerprints at USPS?

Tags: visas, criminal-records

I'm being asked for criminal record history to apply for a visa.

As an American, it looks like the FBI offers this under [Identity History Summary Checks "IdHSC"](https://www.fbi.gov/services/cjis/identity-history-summary-checks).

I'd like to use the option of filling an Electronic Departmental Order "EDO" by registering on [edo.cijs.gov](https://www.edo.cjis.gov/#/) and paying $18 online.

Then I'd like to submit the actual fingerprints electronically at one of the post offices offering the service.

**Do I need an appointment for digital fingerprinting at USPS?**

The locations all list:

> Preregistration Required ()

But it's unclear what that means.

**Is there a fee?**

I already paid $18 to the FBI for the request. Do I have to pay USPS too?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*I created this question for the future reference since I didn't find this info until at the actual post office, which was frustrating since I had to travel to a different city to visit an eligible post office.*

They warn there may be a processing lag between each of the steps, in my experience everything went through instantly, including them sending out the results. - Theoretically you could do the whole process: apply and get results within minutes.

Here are the steps in order for the full-digital process to get a FBI report:

1.) Register on [edo.cjis.gov](https://www.edo.cjis.gov/#/).

2.) Complete the $18 payment for the EDO.

3.) [Register on USPS's website for digital fingerprint capture](https://ips.usps.com/IdentityCapture/) with your EDO order number. This must be what they mean by "Pre-registration required" however it's impossible to find this info or link online.

4.) Go to an [eligible post office during service hours](https://www.edo.cjis.gov/#/org/USPS). No appointment required.

5.) A post office employee will take your fingerprints and charge you $50.

6.) The FBI will send an email notification when the results are ready. Use the link in the original confirmation email of the EDO to login and view the results.

Comment: Yes but they didn't have the info - basically said it's fine if you're set up with the FBI. In the end, calling the FBI resulted in them sending me over an email with the USPS link posted here.

Comment: Where did you apostille the document?

Comment: It's OK to accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

As you found you have to pay an additional $50 at the post office, so the total is $68.
The extra $50 is sort of hidden as they say something about additional fees may apply.

Note: There are websites on the FBI-Approved Channeler list that will fingerprint and give the full report for less than $50.

See:
https://www.fbi.gov/services/cjis/identity-history-summary-checks
Option 3: Submit Your Request to an FBI-Approved Channeler